How to fix the "detailed" date time format in Files application of Gnome 46
The new version (46.0) of the Files application in 24.04 allows the user to select between two formats in its Preferences: Simple and Detailed.
However, the date format in Detailed option is in the US standard (e.g. 05/22/2024). I want to change it to the normal 2024-05-22 or at least 22/05/2024 format. I changed the Regional Format in Language Support to English (United Kingdom) and restarted the Gnome session, but nothing changed.
Also, why are the seconds missing from the time?
What is the trick to set a sensible format?

Cause
This is because the date format rely on translating a string for every different region, even within English speaking countries like US, UK, Canada, Australia, etc. It seems these regional formats weren't translated in time for release, probably because strings rarely get changed from US English. Thus the default US date is used with different locales.

Also, why are the seconds missing from the time?

This is the intention of the designers, to save space in the view.
Solution
The proper solution is for someone to translate the date formats in GNOME's "Damned Lies" for their respective locale and then wait for the translation to arrive in your distribution.
If you're in a hurry and want to change translations that manually, there are instructions in this forum post on how to do that.

Just for reference, I am adding detailed information from the accepted answer by @KhalidAbuShawarib, because I want to list the exact steps I followed from the forum post mentioned.

I was already using the UK English formats (see GNOME Settings → System → Region & Language)



So, I downloaded the British English (en_GB) .po file from https://l10n.gnome.org/vertimus/nautilus/main/po/en_GB/ into a temporary location.

I edited this file by modifying the 9 lines starting with msgstr (search for the string src/nautilus-date-utilities in this file) like this:


#. Translators: date and time in 24h format,
#. * i.e. "12/31/2023 23:59"
#: src/nautilus-date-utilities.c:83
#, no-c-format
msgid "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
msgstr "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

#. Translators: date and time in 12h format,
#. * i.e. "12/31/2023 11:59 PM"
#: src/nautilus-date-utilities.c:90
#, no-c-format
msgid "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"
msgstr "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

#. Translators: this is the word "Today" followed by
#. * a time in 24h format. i.e. "Today 23:04"
#: src/nautilus-date-utilities.c:119
#, no-c-format
msgid "Today %-H:%M"
msgstr "Today %H:%M:%S"

#. Translators: this is the word Today followed by
#. * a time in 12h format. i.e. "Today 9:04 PM"
#: src/nautilus-date-utilities.c:126
#, no-c-format
msgid "Today %-I:%M %p"
msgstr "Today %H:%M:%S"

#. Translators: this is the word Yesterday followed by
#. * a time in 24h format. i.e. "Yesterday 23:04"
#: src/nautilus-date-utilities.c:137
#, no-c-format
msgid "Yesterday %-H:%M"
msgstr "Yesterday %H:%M:%S"

#. Translators: this is the word Yesterday followed by
#. * a time in 12h format. i.e. "Yesterday 9:04 PM"
#: src/nautilus-date-utilities.c:144
#, no-c-format
msgid "Yesterday %-I:%M %p"
msgstr "Yesterday %H:%M:%S"

#. Translators: this is the day of the month followed by the abbreviated
#. * month name followed by the year i.e. "3 Feb 2015"
#: src/nautilus-date-utilities.c:152
#, no-c-format
msgid "%-e %b %Y"
msgstr "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

#. Translators: this is the day number followed by the full month
#. * name followed by the year followed by a time in 24h format
#. * with seconds i.e. "3 February 2015 23:04:00"
#: src/nautilus-date-utilities.c:163
#, no-c-format
msgid "%-e %B %Y %H:%M:%S"
msgstr "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

#. Translators: this is the day number followed by the full month
#. * name followed by the year followed by a time in 12h format
#. * with seconds i.e. "3 February 2015 09:04:00 PM"
#: src/nautilus-date-utilities.c:171
#, no-c-format
msgid "%-e %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p"
msgstr "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

You may prefer other formats. Please, see man date for details about the % format sequences.

I saved the file and converted it using the command:

$ msgfmt nautilus.po-ui.main.en_GB.po -o nautilus.mo


I copied the .mo file into /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/ directory. Please, note that there should not be a file with name nautilus.mo in that directory already. Also note that this will affect all users in the system; I have  not  found any per user location (like ~/.local/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/) to store this file.

After that, there should not by any need to reboot or restart your GNOME session. Killing all nautilus* processes, if any, should be enough.

Start the Files application (/usr/bin/nautilus) and look at the Modified column for example:



